# combining @NamedQuery from JPA and @Filter from Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have @NamedQuery.  I want to add a lot of different filters to the query as per condition at runtime. There is another concept of @Filter in Hibernate. can this concept be a merge to have a combined result?

suppose I have 
`@NamedQuery(name="Users.someUsers",query="select u from Users where firstname='bob'")`

suppose I want to filter the result according to some other parameter.
can I add @Filter that can do the trick?

supposed I want to an add age filer or a place filter over the existing `Users.someUsers` by enabling the corresponding filter on the underlying hibernate session?

Comment: Man, just supposes? Make some tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to define named queries and filters at entity level and expect named queries to have filters which you defined.

I wrote a test for it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name=DepartmentEntity.GET_DEPARTMENT_BY_ID, query=DepartmentEntity.GET_DEPARTMENT_BY_ID_QUERY),})
@FilterDef(name="deptFilter", parameters={@ParamDef( name="name", type="string")})
@Filters( {@Filter(name="deptFilter", condition=":name = name")})
public class DepartmentEntity implements Serializable {

    static final String GET_DEPARTMENT_BY_ID_QUERY = "from DepartmentEntity d where d.id = :id";
    public static final String GET_DEPARTMENT_BY_ID = "GET_DEPARTMENT_BY_ID";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now you can use both like this:

```
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
    Filter filter = session.enableFilter("deptFilter");
    filter.setParameter("name", name);
    return (DepartmentEntity) session.getNamedQuery(DepartmentEntity.GET_DEPARTMENT_BY_ID)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .uniqueResult();
```

Query generated by hibernate:

```
select department0_.ID as ID1_3_, department0_.NAME as NAME2_3_ from DEPARTMENT department0_ where ? = department0_.name and department0_.ID=?
```

You will need to add filters to session and then create named query. If this doesn't cover your use case then post example exactly what you want to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [CriteriaQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html) is built for. It allows you to create queries at runtime.
Avoid using named queries for queries which you want to build at runtime based on user input.

Example

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<EntityType> criteria = builder.createQuery(EntityType.class);

Root<EntityType> root = criteria.from(EntityType.class);

criteria.where(
  builder.equal(root.get("owner"), "something")
);
 // Any conditions can be added to criteria here ar runtime based on user input

List<Topic> topics = entityManager
.createQuery(criteria)
.getResultList();
```

Named queries are precompiled at `EntityManagerFactory` startup, so they add performance benefits as long as queries are static, but for dynamic queries consider using CriteriaQueries

Comment: can I combine them both?  Can I add a dynamic part of the named query through criteria?

Comment: No. Named queries are static queries and get pre-compiled at start up time. You can’t change them at runtime. Other options is to build JPQL at runtime by string concatenation based on conditions, and execute query using EntityManager.createQuery(String dynamicJpqlQuery) and execute in same way as yoy execute named query using Query or TypedQuery methods